# How to get meaningful error msg from truffle unit test?

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing, error, unittesting

I am writing unit tests in truffle. No matter it's solidity unit tests or js unit tests, all of the error msg I can get is:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:114:19)
```

Is there anyway to get more informative error msg?

Comment: Currently it is not possible, but next version of solidity 0.4.22 will have a way to generate a revert with an error message.